# How we can write multiple condition in style using WPF/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

suppose i have a one data-grid in main window form. i would like to apply cell style like background  for different column depend upon cell value condition.

is this possible? any example..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx

Comment: It probably helps to know that this is called "conditional formatting". Many examples of this on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [MultiDataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger.aspx) class.

example:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <MultiDataTrigger>
           <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
               <Condition Binding="{Binding XXXX}" Value="YYYY"/>
               <Condition Binding="{Binding WWWW}" Value="ZZZZ"/>
           </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```